# How can I keep the user permission on a table that is dropped and recreated?

Tags: sql-server

I drop, create and bulk insert a table weekly for a user, but the user's permission is removed from the table each time I do that. I right click on the table name and add them each time. Is there a way to keep their name in the permissions?

Comment: You could have that table on a schema and grant privileges on that schema instead of the table. This way every time you drop or recreate the table on that schema it'll keep the privileges since you won't drop the schema. Is creating the new schema an option for you?

Comment: @Ronaldo I'm not sure what you mean, sorry. Do you mean like the DB the table is on? Thanks.

Comment: Create an script with `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`, `CREATE TABLE` and `GRANT PERMISSIONS` and execute a weekly job that executes the script. BTW, the same script can fill the new table with the current values.

Comment: A schema works somehow like a folder. You can see the schemas you have on a database by expanding `dbYourDatabase > Security > Schemas`. Now, if you expand `dbYourDatabase > Tables` you'll notice that the tables are listed with the pattern `dbo.YourTable`. That `dbo` refers to the schema the table belongs to. I gessed `dbo`because it's a default schema, but there could be other schemas and you can create schemas when needed. Is it clearer now (despite my simplistic explanation of a schema)?

Comment: @Ronaldo, makes sense. It is dbo. How do I grant privileges to a schema?

Comment: Basicaly `GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA :: YourSchema TO YourUser;`, But before you choose that approach check the doc of [GRANT Schema Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-schema-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Notice that the privileges you give on the schema level will be inherited by any object you create or already exists on that schema. Also, consider @McNets suggestion as an option with less impact or change on the database structure.

Comment: @Ronaldo so add something like "GRANT SELECT ON OBJECT:: TEST.MEMBERS TO ESMITH" to the end of the script that creates the table and does the bulk insert?

Comment: Why not just TRUNCATE the table instead of dropping it?

Comment: No. Once you granted the privileges on the schema anything you create on the schema will inherite the privileges and there's no need to add that grant on the schema or execute it more than once. thy it on you dev environment to understand the behavior: create a new schema, grant the Select privilege on the schema to a user, create a new table and execute a select; drop the table, create a new one and execute a select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you drop and re-create the table, it becomes a new object. If the principal is granted access to that specific object, all security related to it will be dropped as well.

If you `truncate` the table or `delete from` it, the security will be preserved. You'll need to slightly adjust your bulk import process.

Alternatively, you could run the import with elevated permissions, and have that process execute a `GRANT SELECT` for that principal. But I would recommend against that.